# Installing existant laravel project on wamp for pre-production

Tags: php, git, laravel-5, wampserver

I have a existing laravel project that I have been working on for a while now.

I have to put it in a test environnement to show it to my employer. 
My problem is that I have no clue how to use my git repo of the project to put it on a fresh installation of wamp server.

1 - I have tried to install it as a whole but failed.

2- Then, I tried creating a fresh copy of Laravel base architecture (that worked) and after, replacing the files I modified on my existing project over on the fresh Laravel project. Turns out, it can not find my login.php page and I am stuck at that point.

So I want to find the easiest way to clone a git repo with an existing Laravel project directly on a wamp server and make it work.

I have been trying for several weeks, please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here are some simple steps to create a copy of your Laravel5 project on another server:

1. Setup the server (Databases, PHP and so on) and *install Composer*. If you are local, composer should already be installed
2. Clone the repository and copy the content to the htdocs or var/www folder, depending on your server system
3. Now execute **composer update** to load all dependencies
4. Last but not least, setup your `.env` file. Use the `.env.example` from Laravel5, add your credentials, generate a key with `php artisan key:generate`

**That's it**. Now your Laravel5 project should run.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot, I had to use rewrite_module to make it work and a bit of changing in the httpd.conf but I now have a login page.